# Direction of the normal vector to the decision hyper-plane of support vector machine

Tags: matlab, geometry, svm

Given the coefficients of the hyper-plane of the support vector machine for classifying an mxn-dimensional dataset into two classes as an n-dimensional vector, how can we find out the direction (e.g. cosines) of the normal vector to that hyper-plane?
FYI, the coefficients and the support vectors were calculated by using the svmtrain function in Matlab.

Comment: You can remove “SVM” from the question. You are looking to compute the normal to a hyper plane based on the plane’s coefficients. Post that question on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) to get a good answer.

Comment: Better yet: Research first and find e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524246/why-are-the-coefficients-of-the-equation-of-a-plane-the-normal-vector-of-a-plane).

Comment: NicoSchertler  Cris Luengo Thanks a lot!